# Applying data mining techniques on Firebase

Tags: android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-mining

Can i perform data mining techniques on a Firebase's Database?
I want to classify data that i will get from the user and come with some results from it for my Android graduation project.
The project core is Data mining, so is Firebase friendly for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database API is optimized for synchronizing data between large numbers of users. It is not ideally suited for data mining, which typically requires different access patterns to the data.

Note that it's quite possible and common to combine the Firebase Realtime Database with other data storage solutions to server all needs of an app. Many developers combine Firebase with BigQuery, using the latter for their data analysis. That way your users/app can write straight to the Firebase Database (or Cloud Firestore). You'll e.g. use Cloud Functions to pass that data onto BigQuery, where you do the analysis on it. Any analysis result you'll write back to the Firebase Database, where clients can read them. With this approach Firebase functions as a proxy between your (mobile) clients and your custom cloud infrastructure.

Comment: BigQuery states it in the name, for LARGE projects no? If you have an app with < 1,000 users, you could potentially use cloud function to call into the DB. and with android, you can call a service every morning, or hour, or whatever, to call that function and send out notifications for the data you find...